# Getting profiling-related features to work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, profiling, eclipse-cdt, gprof

I want to profile a C/C++ app with Eclipse CDT (actually it's the nsight version of Eclipse, but hopefully that shouldn't matter). So, I installed appropriate plugins, as described here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/PluginInstallHelp

Then I tried to follow the instructions in this (official) guide:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/GProf/User_Guide

Unfortunately, I don't see the dialogs you find at that link (under Project Settings | Build | Settings there's no Tool Settings tab), and some of their instructions assume an autotools project (I use CMake).

Also, just opening gmon.out doesn't do anything extraordinary, I just see some binary gibberish.

So, how can I get the gprof-related tools/plugins in Eclipse to actually work?

Comment: It doesn't sounds like the plug-ins are installed properly. The gmon.out should be a special icon (as in the screenshot from your link). If it is the right icon, but the wrong editor is opening, try right-clicking on file and choosing open with. I just tested in out on my linux machine, I had to install "GProf Integration" plug-in from Neon release site as AFAICT it is not included with CDT by default.

Comment: @JonahGraham: See clarification. I did install the plugins and it seemed to go fine unless I'm missing something. Maybe it's the fact that I'm using nsight?

Comment: Hi @einpoklum, not sure here what is going on. One thing I can help on, the "Tool Settings" tab only applies to CDT "managed" projects, writing your own makefiles or using CMake means that your project won't have them. Did you try the right-click open as on the gmon.out? If you check installed plugins do you see the gprof one there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q61W1.png